# Animating Camera with bounds returns nullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, bounds

I am develepoing an app that needs to  view various map points at the same time. I am trying to animate camera with bounds and Builder, but it's returning null every time, and I checked the coordinates and the .build() and all of them have data. this is the code.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builderMap = new LatLngBounds.Builder();           
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            if(location!=null)
            {
                Log.i("MapACtivity","builder includes myLocation");
                builderMap.include(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));             
                coordinate_bounds= coordinate_bounds +1;
            }
            for(CircleContact myContact : newCircle.getMembers())
            {
                if(myContact.getLatitude()!=0 && myContact.getLongitude()!=0)
                {
                    Log.i("MapACtivity","builder includes locations " + myContact.getDevice());
                    Log.i("MapACtivity","Lat " + myContact.getLatitude()+ " longitude" +myContact.getLongitude());
                    builderMap.include(new LatLng(myContact.getLatitude(),myContact.getLongitude()));
                    coordinate_bounds= coordinate_bounds +1;
                }
            }
            if(coordinate_bounds>1)
            {
                Log.i("CircleFragment","builderMap.build()" + builderMap.build().getCenter());
                Log.i("CircleFragment","builderMap.build()" + builderMap.build().northeast);
                Log.i("CircleFragment","builderMap.build()" + builderMap.build().southwest);                
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builderMap.build(), 50));                                                           
            }
```

The log that I get is :

```
builderMap.build()lat/lng: (-11.075408249999999,-75.85188305)
builderMap.build()lat/lng: (-10.078819,-74.748112)
builderMap.build()lat/lng: (-12.0719975,-76.9556541)
```

But it's returning null in this line:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builderMap.build(), 50));
```

and it is not the map because, before I update the camera to my location, and that  doesn't crash, this is the code before trying to get all positions inside the map and it is working fine:

```
MapView mMapView;
mMapView = (MapView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map_locations);                                         
mMap = mMapView.getMap();           
mMap.addMarker(myMarker);                           
CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Location, 15);                            
mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the official google maps android page:

> Note: Only use the simpler method newLatLngBounds(boundary, padding) to generate a CameraUpdate if it is going to be used to move the camera after the map has undergone layout. During layout, the API calculates the display boundaries of the map which are needed to correctly project the bounding box. In comparison, you can use the CameraUpdate returned by the more complex method newLatLngBounds(boundary, width, height, padding) at any time, even before the map has undergone layout, because the API calculates the display boundaries from the arguments that you pass.

And this is how they are setting bounds:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(AUSTRALIA.getCenter(), 10));
```